# Displaying only names of files in listview

Tags: android, listview

In my app am creating some files and storing them in `cache dir`. now from app only I want to access this files so i get them in a `ListView` by giving the path `getExternalCacheDir().getAbsolutePath()`. Here, I get a `ListView` with the whole path of the  files. Instead I just want the file name to be displayed in list.
Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply call `list()` in the diretory to return an array of the file names in that directory:

```
File directory = getExternalCacheDir();
String[] filenames = directory.list();
```

Alternatively, you can call `listFiles()` to get back a `File[]` if that if more useful to you.

HTH